# Using gpu accelerated libSVM in python

Tags: python, gpu, cuda, libsvm

I have been using libSVM in python notebook to classify my dataset and it takes approximately 5 hours for one run and for 5 fold cross validation, it will take almost a day+ time.
I am planning to switch to gpu accelerated libSVM. I could find gpu accelerated libsvm libraries but could not figure out how to install or integrate these in jupyter notebook or pip installation command for gpu accelerated libSVM. For example-
for https://github.com/MKLab-ITI/CUDA/
I have installed the executables svmtrain.exe but could not find a document on using gpu accelerated svm-train in jupyter notebook.